# Sort vector of inner class java

Tags: java, vector, inner-classes

I am learning java I have to change a program from c++ to java. For the input:
10
26 77
12 37
14 18
19 96
71 95
91 9
98 43
66 77
2 75
94 91
I am getting an error. I've never used comparator before.Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    static int n;

    static public class punct
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    static punct v[];
    static Vector <punct> vec;
    static boolean sortY(punct a,punct b)
    {
        return (a.y < b.y);
    }

    static boolean sortX(punct a,punct b)
    {
        return (a.x < b.x);
    }

    static int myDistance(punct a1,punct a2)
    {

        return ((a1.x - a2.x) * (a1.x - a2.x) + (a1.y - a2.y) * (a1.y - a2.y)) ;
    }   

    static int devideAndConquer(int left,int right)
    {
        int d;
        int c;
        if(right - left <= 2)
        {
            d = (1000000000);

            for(int i = left; i < right ; i++ )
            {
                for(int j = i + 1 ; j<= right; j++)
                {
                    d = Math.min(myDistance(v[i], v[j]),d);
                }
            }
            Arrays.sort(v,new Comparator <punct>()
            {
                public int compare(punct a, punct b)
                {
                    return (int) a.y - b.y;
                }
            });

            return d;
        }
        else
        {
            int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;

            d = Math.min(devideAndConquer(left, middle),devideAndConquer(middle + 1, right));

            int l = left;
            int r = middle+1;

            vec.clear();
            while( (l <= middle) && (r <= right) )
            {
                if( sortY(v[l], v[r]) == true)
                {
                    vec.add(v[l]);
                    l++;
                }
                else
                {
                    vec.add(v[r]);
                    r++;
                }
            }

            while( l <= middle )
            {
                vec.add(v[l]);
                l++;
            }

            while( r <= right )
            {
                vec.add(v[r]);
                r++;
            }

            for(int i = left, k = 0; i<=right; i++,k++)
            {
                v[i] = vec.get(k);
            }

            for(int i = left ; i<= right ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = i+1; (j <= right) && (j-i < 7) ; j++)
                {
                    d = Math.min(myDistance(v[i],v[j]),d);
                }
            }

            return d;
        }
    }

    static void read()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        v = new punct [n+10];
        punct a = new punct();
        for(int i = 0; i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            a.x = scanner.nextInt();
            a.y = scanner.nextInt();
            v[i] = a;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    static void write(int d)
    {
        double x = Math.sqrt(d);
        System.out.print(x);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        read();
        Arrays.sort(v,new Comparator <punct>(){
                    public int compare(punct a, punct b)
                    {
                        return  a.x - b.x;
                    }
                });
        int d = devideAndConquer(0,n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Don't use `Vector`. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main$2.compare(Main.java:137)
 at Main$2.compare(Main.java:1)
 at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:134)

Comment: Never use `a-b` as a comparator function. This will overflow if the distance between the two values is too large. Use [`Integer.compare(a,b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)).

Answer (score 2):

One problem is here in your `read()` method

change

```
    punct a = new punct();  //this line should be in your for loop
    for(int i = 0; i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        a.x = scanner.nextInt();
        a.y = scanner.nextInt();
        v[i] = a;
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i = 0; i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        punct a = new punct(); //moved inside the loop
        a.x = scanner.nextInt();
        a.y = scanner.nextInt();
        v[i] = a;
    }
```

another problem is here

Change

```
   n = scanner.nextInt();
   v = new punct [n+10];
```

to

```
    n = scanner.nextInt();
    v = new punct [n];
```

Oh i missed this one

Change

```
  static Vector <punct> vec;
```

to

```
 static Vector <punct> vec = new Vector<punct>();
```

Comment: And once these are solved, the fact that `vec`is never initialized comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in your read() method:

```
    static void read()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        v = new punct [n];
        for(int i = 0; i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            punct a = new punct();
            a.x = scanner.nextInt();
            a.y = scanner.nextInt();
            v[i] = a;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
```

1. initialization of the array: `v = new punct[n+10] should be v = new punct[n]`
2. creation of punct object (`punct a = new punct();`) should be in the for-loop

Also, you should initialise the vec object: `static Vector <punct> vec = new Vector<punct>();`

---

Another small remark: instead of `d = (1000000000);` you can use `d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Answer (score 0):

The next one [problem] is that 10 of elements in your `v` array are all nulls, that is why you get `NullPointerException`. The core is here: `v = new punct [n+10];`

You have to change it to `v = new punct [n];'` or increase iterations number in your `for` loop.